# How to make <div> scrollable from bottom

Tags: html, css

I made a table inside a div to make it scrollable;

```html
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100px; width:100px;">
  <table
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This table is scrollable from top to bottom. How can I make the table's overflow start at the bottom and make it scroll upwards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use javascript for this. Using `scrollTop` for accessing the scroll offset from the top (default is 0). So you have to get the div's height and set the `scrollTop` of the div to its height. To get the height, I used `getBoundingClientRect().height`

```js
let tableDiv = document.getElementById('main');
tableDiv.scrollTop = tableDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

```html
<div id="main" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:100px; width:100px;">
<table
<thead>
<tr>
<th>a</th>
<th>b</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>t</td>
<td>t</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>t</td>
<td>t</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML content:

```
<div class="scorllable-table" id="scrollTable">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>b</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>t</td>
        <td>t</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Your CSS content:

```
.scorllable-table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

If you want to do this using JavaScript only, then please try with this.

```
var scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("scrollTable");
scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight;
```

If you want to do this using jQuery, then use the below code.

```
$("#scrollTable").scrollTop($("#scrollTable")[0].scrollHeight);
```

If you want to smooth scroll, then try with this.

```
$('#scrollTable').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $('#scrollTable')[0].scrollHeight
}, 500);
```

Enjoy, Thanks. :)